# Setup web server for django backend: Nginx and Gunicorn configuration before database migration

Tags: django, database, deployment, server, production-environment

Is it possible to setup Nginx and Gunicorn on my web server before executing "python manage.py migrate", since my database server is not ready yet?

Chatgpt recommended me to execute first the migration and then the configuration of Nginx and Gunicorn. So I'm unsure if I can proceed without any problems